# ¿Por qué recibo este error en un caso pero no en el otro? "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cantidad' referenced before assignment."

Tags: python, funciones, variables-globales

Tengo una duda entre dos códigos que son muy similares, pero sin embargo uno de ellos arroja error.

El primer código es:

```
cantidad = 0
def sumador(n):
  cantidad += 1
  n += 1
  return n
sumador(5)
```

Al ejecutarlo arroja el siguiente error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cantidad' referenced before assignment.

Entiendo que se produce porque la variable "cantidad" está referenciada antes de la función y luego se intenta modificar su valor dentro de la función, lo cual no es posible.

Sin embargo al ejecutar el siguiente código:

```
numero = 10
def operacion(n):
  numero = 100
  return n * numero
operacion(5)
print(numero)
```

En este caso no hay error, aún cuando la variable "numero" al igual que en el ejemplo anterior está referenciada antes de la función, tomando luego otro valor dentro de la función.

Mi duda es: ¿Por qué en el primer caso indica el error y no así en el segundo ejemplo?

Comment: ¿Qué querrías que hiciera `cantidad` exactamente? Parece como un contador de cuántas veces se ha ejecutado la función, en cuyo caso podrías referenciarla usando `global cantidad` para referenciarla desde dentro de la función.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python no tiene un declarador de variables, infiere la declaración cuando se le asigna un valor entonces, analicemos tu primer ejemplo

```
cantidad = 0 // variable global
def sumador(n):
  cantidad += 1
  n += 1
  return n
sumador(5)
```

al estar "declarada" la variable cantidad de forma global, eso no le dice a la función que puede accederla simple y llanamente con el nombre, al usar el mismo nombre dentro de la función el intérprete de Python piensa que estas usando otra variable `cantidad`, variable que no ha sido definida por ende la estas usando sin haberla declarado y te arroja el error

analizando el segundo fragmento de código

```
numero = 10
def operacion(n):
  numero = 100
  return n * numero
operacion(5)
print(numero)
```

en este caso dentro de la función declaras **otra** variable numero que le corresponde a la función, y digo declaras porque le asignas un valor

Entonces para usar la variable global dentro de una función debes usar la palabra reservada `global` como ya te mostró @IDanny7:

```
cantidad = 0
def sumador(n):
    global cantidad
    cantidad += 1
    n += 1
    return n
print(sumador(5))
```

o también puedes usar la palabra clave `nonlocal` que esta hace que se vaya al espacio de nombres superior (scope superior)

```
cantidad = 0
    def sumador(n):
        nonlocal cantidad
        cantidad += 1
        n += 1
        return n
    print(sumador(5))
```

Comment: Gracias por la explicación, me queda claro ahora. Mi error tal como indicas era que la variable "cantidad" no está definida dentro de la función a diferencia del segundo ejemplo. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

En la primera función `cantidad` la declaras globalmente, pero para hacer uso de esa variable dentro de la función sumador tienes que usar la palabra reservada `global`.

Como no haces uso de `global` la variable `cantidad` no ha sido declarada de forma local en la función, por lo que no tiene valor asignado.

Ejemplo:

```
cantidad = 0
def sumador(n):
    global cantidad
    cantidad += 1
    n += 1
    return n
print(sumador(5))
```

Ahora en el segundo ejemplo que muestras funciona porque `numero` es declarado tanto de forma global como de forma local en la función, ya que estás asignando un valor directamente.

Answer (score 1):

En el primer caso le estas diciendo que sume 1 a una variable sin valor en cambio en el segundo caso como si que estas asignándole un valor no te da ningún problema.

Te dejo un ejemplo como si funcionaria el primer caso:

```
cantidad = 0
def sumador(n):
  cantidad = 1
  cantidad += 1
  n += 1
  return n
sumador(5)
```